# Application to set audio output device per application windows

Tags: windows

How do you programmatically change the output device of another application running under windows 7 or 10 64bit?

I know it is possible to some extend because of software such as http://www.chevolume.com/

My goal is to set video games to my headphones and netflix to the tv control and music to the sound system, etc.